# deduce variance from precision for bathymetry dataset

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, precision, blue

I mean to merge 2 gridded dataset of bathymetry using 
BLUE (Best Linear Unbiased Estimate).

$merged = \frac{(\sigma_1^2 * dataset2 + \sigma_2^2 * dataset1)}{(sigma_1^2 + sigma_2^2)}$

I know the variance of only dataset2 ($\sigma_2$), while the other is unknown.

I know, though, that the precision of dataset1 is 1 meter, being the 
 dataset made of integer values. So I assume that the probability 
that the true value of bathymetry in one grid point is

$P( value - 1m <= value <= value + 1m) = 
 P( value - 3\sigma_1 <= value <= value + 3\sigma_1) = 99.7%$

so the standard deviation is $\sigma_1 = \frac{1}{3} m$

and the variance is $\sigma_1^2 = \frac{1}{9} m^2$

Do you think this is correct?